# What is the benefit of handling events with pure javascript over jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dont understand why anyone would handle event triggers with pure js now that jquery exists. Can someone explain to me why it would be beneficial for me to learn both ways of programming events? Is the pure js way more flexible?

Comment: JQuery provides an abstraction to JavaScript code that often needs to be performed for the purpose of simplifying. Since JQuery is an abstraction it might be beneficial for you to learn the JavaScript way to understand the basis of how it works. JavaScript may be faster in certain scenarios. That being said it's usually preference. Though, the code to handle events in JavaScript is very basic.

Comment: The `write less, do more` slogan is true though for jQuery and the API is very well documented. MDN  Docs for javascript are also excellent

Comment: Uh, not using jQuery would be one benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As someone that has extensively used jQuery and vanilla JS here are my two cents.*

> jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes
>   things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling,
>   animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works
>   across a multitude of browsers. With a combination of versatility and
>   extensibility, jQuery has changed the way that millions of people
>   write JavaScript.

This quote comes straight from the [official website](https://jquery.com/). There is one part in that quote that is super important to take note.

> that works across a multitude of browsers

Historically, cross browser compatibility was never stable and with the majority of households still using IE that only further caused problems; as there were many issues with how certain features were implemented or just not implemented at all.

This is why jQuery became so popular as it was one of the first libraries that ensured this cross platform stability.

Today, browsers are doing a much better job staying up to date with most of the new javascript features. So the question begs, do you still need jQuery?

> write less, do more

Is the popular jQuery slogan. However, maintaining jQuery code is not easy as it is not very readable once your front end application becomes more complex. In the end, you may write less, but you spend more time debugging it.

Additionally you pay in performance. While this is not noticeable on small applications. It is noticeable on medium to large applications that require a heavy front end design.

Conclusion? Vanilla Javascript is the way to go in 2019. If you're worried about cross platform compatibility, I recommend checking out [babel](https://babeljs.io/) and [polyfills](https://polyfill.io/v3/)

If you're looking to handle a dynamic website checkout any of the javascript frameworks: [reactjs](https://reactjs.org/), [angular](https://angular.io/), or [vuejs](https://vuejs.org/)

Comment: thanks, I had a feeling it had something to deal with performance. Coming from a Ruby background so this information is helpful.